# Discrepency in calculated Median and the median lines on the box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

The medians of the boxplot vary from when calculated outside ggboxplot function.

I am trying to get a boxplot using the following R code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(scales)
colnames(dataset) <- c("opmode","CO2","Trailer", "Vehicle")
ggboxplot(
  dataset,
  x = "opmode",
  y = "CO2",
  fill = "Trailer",
  palette = "jco",
  facet.by = "Vehicle",
  outlier.shape = 1,
  outlier.size = 0.1
) +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "wilcox",
    aes(group = Trailer, label = ..p.signif..) ,
    hide.ns = TRUE,
    size = 5,
    family = 'sans'
  ) + geom_vline(
    xintercept = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5,
                   12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5
  ),
    linetype = "solid",
    color = "gray",
    size = 0.5
  ) +
  xlab("\nSpeed Category") +
  ylab("CO Emissions (g/s)")  +
  scale_y_log10(labels = label_log(),
                breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x)
                  10 ^ x, n = 4)) + annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 15)) + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15))
```

output of dput(dataset)

```
structure(list(opmode = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CO2 = c(NA, 0, 0.00022, 
0.00023, 0.00023, 0.00026, 0.00026, 0.00027, 0.00027, 0.00028, 
0.00029, 3e-04, 3e-04, 0.00031, 0.00032, 0.00032, 0.00033, 0.00033, 
0.00034, 0.00035, 0.00035, 0.00036, 0.00036, 0.00037, 0.00037, 
0.00038, 0.00038, 0.00039, 0.00039, 4e-04, 4e-04, 0.00041, 0.00041, 
0.00042, 0.00042, 0.00043, 0.00043, 0.00044, 0.00044, 0.00045, 
0.00045, 0.00046, 0.00046, 0.00047, 0.00047, 0.00048, 0.00048, 
0.00049, 0.00049, 5e-04), Trailer = c("With Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"With Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"With Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer", 
"Without Trailer", "With Trailer", "Without Trailer", "With Trailer"
), Vehicle = c("C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", 
"C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", 
"C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", 
"C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", 
"C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", 
"C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13", "C13")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

But the median lines of the boxplot are different from when I calculate outside the ggplot. I am not sure what's happening?

Comment: If edit your question to include the output of `dput(dataset)` we have a better shot at being able to help you. We can't actually run your code without the data set.

Comment: How are you calculating the median outside of ggplot? What function(s) specifically are you using?

Comment: the median is calculated outside through medians <- aggregate(CO2 ~ opmode + Trailer + Vehicle, dataset, median)

Comment: Whenever I see a question along the lines of ("my statistic from ggplot2 is different to my statistc calculated elsewhere", my first thought is that there's a call to either `xlim` or `ylim` rather than `coord_cartesian`.  (`xlim` and `ylim` filter the data and then calculate the statistic, `coord_cartesian` uses the full datset and then "zooms" the plot.  Google for more detail.)  There's no explict call to `xlim` here, but I wonder if there's an implict one in `scale_y_log10`.  Do the medians change if you omit the call?

Comment: ^ Good thinking. For instance, your 2nd row of data has CO2 of `0` which is `-Inf` in log terms so will be omitted before the stat calculation. You might try using `scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans())` instead of `scale_y_log10` as an option to use log spacing (beyond sigma) that won't censor your data.

Comment: That makes sense. I dont want to log transform the data. Just have the yaxis on log scale as the variation is very high and cannot be visualized on a linear scale. Is it possible to just have y axis in log scale and plot the actual points?

Comment: OP: That's a different question!  But self-evidently, the answer is "no":  How can you plot a value on the log scale for which no log-scale equivalent value exists?  As @JonSpring has already pointed out, you have just such a value in your data.

Comment: If your goal is visualization and not mathematical purity, try `pseudo_log_trans` or `log1p` as options that act like a log scale for large numbers, but can accommodate zero values.